# squidGuard: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: server, database, squid, blacklist

I am using ubuntu server 14.04.3 and i am trying to use a **blacklist** in **Squid** with **SquidGuard**.

When i execute the command to create the data base blacklist (being root):

> squidGuard -C all

I get the following error:

> squidGuard: error while loading shared libraries: libdb-6.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What does it mean? how can i solve it?

With "**apt-cache policy squid squidguard**" I got this:

> [apt-cache policy squid squidguard](http://s27.postimg.org/n2ua9op1v/ubuntu_u1a_Om_KO6.png)

I downloaded it from squidguard.org and i used (in the folder of squidguard):

> ./configure
>
> make
>
> make install

Thanks.

Comment: How have you installed squid?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy squid squidguard`

Comment: I used "apt-get squid". With "apt-cache policy squid squidguard" I got this:

http://k30.kn3.net/F65DCC7AC.png

Comment: Your picture is private or you have given an invalid link, Error 403 Forbidden

Comment: I changed the host. Can you see it now? http://s27.postimg.org/n2ua9op1v/ubuntu_u1a_Om_KO6.png

Comment: `squidguard` isn't installed via the Ubuntu repositories. How have you installed squidguard? Try this `sudo apt-get install squidguard`

Comment: Ok. I'll try it later and i'll coment the results.

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one option:

- Remove your self-compiled version and install the official Ubuntu version with `apt-get`
- Compile your version again with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install checkinstall
  make clean
  ./configure --prefix=/usr
  make
  sudo checkinstall
  ```

Comment: I've installed squidGuard from the begining and now i have other error with the <squidGuard -C all>

http://s13.postimg.org/rxcrj2pcn/Squiderror2.png